# Android, ROOM query with embedded list of objects

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I am using `ROOM` and I am trying to get a vehicle name that has a specific `Card.Code`.

the entity classes are like that

```
@Entity(tableName = "vehicles")
data class Vehicle(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cards") val cards: List<Card>?
)

@Entity
data class Card(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "code") val code: String
)
```

my issue is that I don't know how to write correctly the SQL query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my solution is like that

```
@Query("SELECT name FROM vehicles WHERE cards LIKE '%' || :cardCode || '%'")
fun getVehicleNameOfCard(cardCode: String): String?
```

but I don't like it and I prefer something better

Answer (score 3):

I would model the `One-to-Many Relationship` between `Vehicle` and `Card` using a `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT`. Then, whenever you want to get the `Vehicle` name that has a specific `Card` you can make a query that joins both tables and selects the `name` column on those rows in which `cardCode` String is equal to the one given in the argument.

```
@Entity(tableName = "vehicles")
data class Vehicle(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String
)
```

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = arrayOf(ForeignKey(
            entity = Vehicle::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("vehicle_id"))
       )
)
data class Card(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val cardId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "code") val code: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "vehicle_id") val vehicleId: Int,
)
```

```
@Query("SELECT vehicles.name
 FROM vehicles, card 
 WHERE vehicles.id == card.vehicle_id
 AND card.code == :cardCode")
fun getVehicleNameOfCard(cardCode: String): String?
```

Since Room is not an ORM, but just a SQLite wrapper, it doesn't handle embedded lists of objects for you. You can either flatten the list of Cards to a String using a [TypeConverter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/TypeConverter) (like I think you are doing now) or you can also opt to use the [@Relation annotation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation).

For more information in how to deal with Relationships in Room, you can [check this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships).